# Detect the Touch on the borders of an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I am implementing an Image cropper, which have a circle area on top of the image. The area of image inside the circle has to be cropped. Now I have to give a scaling functionality to the cropping view. But my requirement is that I have to scale the cropping view, when the user touch on the border of UiView and pan. So that I cannot use Pinch gesture. I have attached an image to get a clear idea of my requirement. Can anyone give an optimised solution for the same.

[image]

Comment: If it's a perfect circle and since you know the touch location, it's quite easy with simple math to know if you are in the allowed area or not.

Comment: you can get an idea from this https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor

Comment: Brother sree check my answer.I updated now.

Comment: @Lame I know with a simple Math it will resolve. But I couldn't find a way to the point between inner and outer circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to identify the touch on edges of a circle. Basically, I had an UIView on which I have given a corner radius of half of the width of UIView to get a circle look and border thickness of 20px.

I have the radius of circle from the outer edge and inner edge of the circle border, which I can get from the view frame and the border thickness values. Then I calculated the radius based on the touch x,y and center x,y using the equation **radius^2 = (touchX-centerX)^2 + (touchY-centerY)^2**. If calculated radius is in b/w the inner radius and outer radius, touch is on the edge of circle. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Good brother for finding solution in another way so I upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solution and I got it.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewCircleTouchPoint;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   float xValue,yValue;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize viewCircleTouchPoint;
```

Now you can use two option

**First Option:touch Event method**

According to me when I touch the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewCircleTouchPoint.frame.size);
  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"txNTO.png"] drawInRect:viewCircleTouchPoint.bounds];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  viewCircleTouchPoint.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
}
```

According to me when I touch the arrow part of the view I get x value 168 and y value 50.So If it is less than x and y value it won't allow to pan.If it is greater than or equal I set the pan for view.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch =[[event allTouches]anyObject];
  CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:imageCirclePoint];
  NSLog(@"The border touch point is - %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
  NSLog(@"Touch x :%f y: :%f",touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y);
  xValue =touchPoint.x;
  yValue =touchPoint.y;
  if(xValue>=168 && yValue>=50){
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGesture:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [viewCircleTouchPoint addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
  }
}
```

Now the printed result is

[image]

**Second Option:Gesture reconizer**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewCircleTouchPoint.frame.size);
  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"txNTO.png"] drawInRect:viewCircleTouchPoint.bounds];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  viewCircleTouchPoint.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];


  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgesture =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
  tapgesture.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
  viewCircleTouchPoint.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [viewCircleTouchPoint addGestureRecognizer:tapgesture];
}

-(void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:imageCirclePoint];
  NSLog(@"The border touch point is - %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
  NSLog(@"Touch x :%f y: :%f",point.x,point.y);
  if(point.x>=168 && point.y>=50){
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGesture:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [viewCircleTouchPoint addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
  }
}

-(void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesturepan
{
   NSLog(@"The pan gesture recognizer is called");
   .....//do your stuff here
}
```

The printed result for tap

[image]

See my iPhone tried screenshot below.I did not add any imageView for view.

[image]

Comment: I am not using UIImageView for circle. I have given a border of width 25 px for the rounded uiview. So when ever the user touches on border area, the pan gesture should work. So I want an optimized mechanism to detect the touch on circular border area of UIView.

Comment: Brother give self.view instead of imageCirclePoint in code.

Comment: Also you need write pan gesture in tap detection method where you have to put the if condition for border whether touch point is less than or equal.So if it is equal write the pan gesture code inside that.

Comment: Check my answer brother

Comment: Hi user3182143, I guess still u didnt understand my question. I am also aware how to get the point while tapping. Consider the above image as a concentric circle. I want an equation or method, which helps to detect the touch point is between outer and inner circle. Did you get my question.

Comment: You did not use or apply my code in your question.I give you the answer which what you ask in comment.While tapping view,we get the point.See my answer.I tried and give you the solution.You have manually calculate the points for inner circle and outer circle.xValue =touchPoint.x;
  yValue =touchPoint.y;

Comment: I found a solution without manually calculating, which I have posted above. Thanks for the help. Your solution will be useful in some other way.

Comment: Brother we can do like that.But according to your question I gave you the answer.